# How to transform and which machine learning algorithm to use on strange target variable (skewed, non symmetric distribution with spikes)?

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, data-transformation

I have a classic, simple regression problem - predict continuous target variable y based on the number (100s) of predictors. See sample of the data set below.

I am dealing with the following distribution of target variable (strange form, skewed, non symmetric, with spikes (please see picture below).

What to do with this target (how to transform it)?

Which machine learning algorithm to use (it is a regression problem)?

I have hundreds of predictors and I am trying to predict continuous target using a regression model. Target represents purchase value in USD (rounded to whole number/integer). I have 100000 cases/observations with hundreds of numeric predictors (some continuous, some factors already coded as integers). For distribution/values of target please see below picture.

[image]

Data looks something like this (it has more columns/predictors, y is a target variable (above is it's distribution), continuous/numeric):

[image]

Comment: Can you provide more information as to what your predictors are and what you are trying to model? What is your expected output?

Comment: @MWaz I have edited the question providing more info. Predictors are a mixed bag of numeric and ordinal with not so strange distributions. There are hundreds of them.

Comment: The dependent variable marginal distribution doesn't mean much at all, so we can't actually answer the question without looking more into the data. What is that variable meaning? Is it a count, a frequency, a proportion, or something else?

Comment: @Firebug I have added a bit more about the data. Target represents purchase value. It is rounded to nearest USD so it is an integer in the data set. I have many (hundreds) of predictors. Some continuous/numeric some are factors (already coded as integers). Does this help? If not, please tell me what more info can I provide. Thanks. My first idea is to locate the spikes and undersample the observations at those spikes so that I smooth the distribution (remove spikes).

Comment: There are 550 points per scan, right? So you are trying to predict a vector in a 550 dimensional space based on "hundreds" of predictor variables? Perhaps you could say that you are only trying to predict the sum of the integrated area-under-curve for the top 10 peaks? Or perhaps you are trying to predict the centroids of the peaks? Still not clear to me what you trying to predict.

Comment: @PeterLeopold The problem is much simpler. I have a continuous target y (dollar value of purchase). And I have a bunch of predictors. I need to build a regression model that would predict y ( based on predictors (of course, transformed and selected subset of them) . Please see screenshot of sampled data set (a few rows and a few columns/predictors). I have posted the distribution of target y just that you see it is nasty. The question is first what to do with target y (transform it and how, undersample at spikes, leave it as it is) and only second which machine learning algorithm to use.

Comment: There are some outliers in your data (maybe), that may be a problem. A linear model requires the residuals to be normally distributed, so try building one and check the residuals.